# I am looking for an Arduino Zero cmake enviroment

Tags: arduino, cmake, arm, zero

I am trying to get cmake working with an Arduino zero/m0.
I was trying to get it working based on the work of tmpsantos at https://github.com/tmpsantos/Arduino-CMake-Template but without success.

Comment: I use http://inotool.org/ with a makefile

Comment: Thanks for the link. inotool looks nice but, why a new ide if one can solve for a much bigger user group with cmake.

Comment: I just use vi, no ide and my makefile is one liner: `all: $(wildcard src/*) $(wildcard lib/*.cpp) 
        ino build && ino upload`

Comment: But the Arduino Zero is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Hi I wrote now a CMake Project and placed it on github.
https://github.com/maxbader/Arduino-CMake-Template
It is not perfect but working